# Conditionally disable buttons in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have two input fields and a button:

```
<Item regular >
    <Input onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({newEmail: text})} value={this.state.newEmail}/>
</Item>

<Item regular >
    <Input onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({confirmEmail: text})} value={this.state.confirmEmail}/>
</Item>

<Button  onPress={() => this.update()} style={styles.updateButton} block> 
    <Text> Send </Text>
</Button>
```

What I want to do is :

`OnTextChange` check that :
These two fields are == and they pass `reg.text(email)` I have defined, 
if so, enable `UpdateButton`. Else keep it disabled.
How do I do such validation in react-native?
I tried writing a function for `onChangeText` in the constructor, but I couldn't get it to work.

I had:

```
  constructor() {
 super();
this.state = {
newEmail: '',
confirmEmail: '',
};
}

handleEmailChange = (evt) => this.setState({ newEmail: evt.target.value });

<Input onChangeText={this.handleEmailChange} value={this.state.newEmail}/>
```

Because I tried to handle the input in the handleEmailChange so I could check for both, but after every letter written, the previous would get overwritten.
That's the part I'm unsure about. 
In Angular I have achieved the same using onChange() and then the ngModel to pass the input values and check there.
But here I don't know how to pass the values onChangeText AND check

Comment: You should show your code anyway.

Comment: @jdv Sorry. Edited. Hopefully it's more clear what part I don't fully understand.

Comment: `Button` component has `disabled` props

Answer (score 0):

In JSX you can check like this.
`{this.state.newEmail && this.state.newEmail===this.state.confirmEmail &&`
`<Button  onPress={() => this.update()} style={styles.updateButton} block>`
   `<Text> Send </Text>`
`</Button>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `react-native` but i think it's easy to redo for `react-native` too. So my code will based on `react`:

You can use `disabled` property of `<Button>` component like below:

```
...
this.state = {
  newEmail: '',
  confirmEmail: '',
  isDisabled: false
}
...
```

My `render` method looks:

```
<div>
   New Email <input type="text" name="newEmail" onChange={this.handleEmailChange} value={this.state.newEmail}/> 
   <br/>
   Confirm Email <input type="text" name="confirmEmail" onChange={this.handleEmailChange} value={this.state.confirmEmail}/>
   <br/>
   <button disabled={this.state.isDisabled}>Woot</button>
 </div>
```

And here is `handleEmailChange` method:

```
handleEmailChange(e){
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value }, () => {
        //since we don't know which field we have changed it's good to check in a callback.
        this.setState({isDisabled: this.state.newEmail !== this.state.confirmEmail})
    })
  }
```

[`Worked example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/97624/)

Comment: Thank you. But Can I have :

 ` this.setState({isDisabled: this.state.newEmail !== this.state.confirmEmail && _validateEmail(this.newEmail)}) `

Becaue I have a _validateEmail function that returns true if the email is valid, and false if it's not.

Comment: @ user9194122 yes you can